# repl hangs for ~15 seconds on each error (emacs + cider + boot)

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm facing a strange behavior whenever I invoke an error in boot-cljs-repl. The repl (actually the entire emacs) hangs for about **15 seconds** and after that I see the following error message below the mode-line:

`error in process filter: Lisp nesting exceeds`max-lisp-eval-depth'`

An error would e.g be calling `(some-nonexisting-function)` from the REPL.

Additionally I get an error message inside the REPL itself. Sorry, for posting the whole thing here - I wouldn't know right now which parts are important:

> ```
> box.webgl> (some-nonexisting-function)
> WARNING: Use of undeclared Var box.webgl/some-nonexisting-function at line 1 <cljs repl>               
> #object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined]                                 
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined                                                    
>     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:30:470), <anonymous>:1\
> :124)                                                                                                  
>     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:30:470), <anonymous>:9\
> :3)                                                                                                    
>     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:30:470), <anonymous>:1\
> 4:4)                                                                                                   
>     at http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:30:465                                            
>     at http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:39:4                                              
>     at cljs.core.MultiFn.call.G__10839__2 (http://localhost:3000/main.out/cljs/core.js:33327:106)      
>     at cljs.core.MultiFn.call.G__10839 [as call] (http://localhost:3000/main.out/cljs/core.js:33594:20\
> )                                                                                                      
>     at .<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.out/weasel/repl.js:184:71)                
>
>     at goog.events.EventTarget.fireListeners (http://localhost:3000/main.out/goog/events/eventtarget.j\
> s:284:23)                                                                                              
>     at Function.goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEventInternal_ (http://localhost:3000/main.out/goog/ev\
> ents/eventtarget.js:381:26)
> ```

Comment: by the way, the same can be invoked by: (throw (js/Error. "err"))

Comment: Could you mention which emacs version you are using and what version of cider/nrepl (printed at the top of the buffer after connecting)

Comment: sure, it's Emacs 24.4.1 and CIDER 0.12.0snapshot (package: 20160313.2315), nREPL 0.2.12

Comment: just to make it complete, these are some other warnings I get when connecting: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15854273/

Answer (score 0):

recently CIDER was changed to automatically supply it's own cider-nrepl and clj-refactor middleware when starting lein, so you can (should) remove these from your ~/.lein/profifiles.clj file if you have them. This will clear up this warning. (remember to update to the latest cider emacs package.

```
WARNING: CIDER's version (0.12.0-snapshot) does not match 
cider-nrepl's version (not installed). Things will break!
```

This is *a* problem and hopefully fixing it clears up your other problems. If not, at least solving this is a prerequisite to debugging it properly.